# How to dynamically create columns and rows using a select query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

for example,

```
select 1,2,3 ;
```

will return *3* columns with *1* row i.e [1,2,3]
, So how to get *3* coulmns with *3* rows with the same content ?

Comment: `SELECT id FROM generate_series(1,3) id;`

Comment: @vyegorov this will only returns only one column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [UNION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-union.html), I think you need something like this

```
select 1 c1,2 c2,3 c3
     union  all
select 1 ,2 ,3 
     union  all
select 1 ,2 ,3
```

Comment: Alternatively use the `values` clause: `select * from ( values (1,2,3), (1,2,3), (1,2,3)) as t (c1, c2, c3)`. Btw: you only need to specify column names in the first statement of a union.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) is a good fit here:

```sql
SELECT rownum, cols.*
  FROM (SELECT 1,2,3) cols
 CROSS JOIN generate_series(1,10) id(rownum);
```

You use `SELECT cols.*` if you need just values without row numbers.